# Retrieve data from JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have this segment code:

```
string responseFromServer; 
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
        {
            responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

ResponseFromServer is a string type variable, contains this data:

```
"[\"10650129201690316481\",\"12590057636606523303\",\"1113994923840324813\"]"
```

This string I need to convert to this string:

"10650129201690316481,12590057636606523303,1113994923840324813"

What is the easiest way to implement it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is most probably what you see in debugger window. use the magnifier icon to see the text.

Comment: @Micheal have you tried to print your output, I think you'll get desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you really need to do is remove the outer brackets and the escaped quotes, simply use `Substring` and `Replace`

```
string convertedRFS = responseFromServer.Substring(1,responseFromServer.Length-2).Replace("\"",String.Empty);
```